# Set and get values from class

Tags: c#, .net

Having a class which internally has several `channels`. For each of the channels we can read or write the same values.

```
 int channel = 2;
 var value = obj.GetValue(channel);
 obj.SetValue(channel, value + 1);
```

Implementing all this `Getters` and `Setters` confuses me since that `C#` allows to have `properties`. Are there better approaches to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A semantically "better" way may be to implement an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

As an example, using the fact that you have internal `Channel` objects:

```
partial class MyClass
{
    public Channel this[int channel]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetChannelObject(channel);
        }

        /*
         * You probably don't want consumers to be able to change the underlying
         * object, so I've commented this out. You could also use a private
         * setter instead if you want to internally make use of the indexing
         * semantic, but since you're most likely just wrapping an IList<Channel>
         * anyway, you probably don't need it.
         *
         * set
         * {
         *     this.SetChannelObject(channel);
         * }
         */
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
int channel = 2;
var value = obj[channel].ValueA;
obj[channel].ValueA = value + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. This allows to to set 1 value. How to set more than 1? Returning a special `Channel` type on the indexer?

Comment: @Razer what do you mean? Like set the same value for channels `1` through `5`?

Comment: No, consider each channel has a `ValueA` and `ValueB`. How to set them? public class Channel { public int ValueA {get; set;} public int ValueB {get; set;} }?

Comment: @Razer Perhaps you should define a `Channel` object then which has these individual properties. The indexer can return this object to which you can set the value: `obj[channelNumber].ValueB = 9;`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That was my idea in the first comment :)